# element on the right of browser when browser if moved from right to left element stays

Tags: html, css

Say I have something like this

```
#navbot {right:20px;
         position:absolute;
         top:50px}
```

When the user moves the browser size from right to left how can I have that element stay there and not move when the browser is moved

Comment: Are you asking *How can I position an element with respect to the position the edges of the browser window held at the time the page is initially rendered?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioning uses a positioned parent to set its origin. If one is not defined, it uses the BODY.

If you have a wrapper for your page, set it to `position:relative`, then have navbot as a child of the wrapper. That way the element uses the wrapper as its origin point, not the browser body.

Comment: Thanks! the problem I'm having with relative is the position is different on different browsers.

Comment: Give the wrapper a fixed with.

Comment: Thanks i tried that too but the text from the right can bleed into the text on the left

Comment: Add padding-right to the wrapper do that it leaves enough space for the positioned element.

Answer (score 1):

Try `position:fixed;` instead of `position:absolute;`
I think it would work well.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider not to position it with `right` so with `left`. If you have a site  container, consider to give it a fixed width and then #navbot relative to the container.

My experience is, every time it happened to me, it was a bad planning of the structure.